# Oracle error: NULL columns: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression -

Tags: oracle

I am trying to append two tables together, they don't have quite the same columns but contain data for the same clients. the table called "outcome" contains survey results from clients collected in 1 month and the table "checkpoint" contains survey results from clients collected six months after. I tried to append those two tables and ensured that there is the same number of columns by introducing NULL columns so that the number of columns match in both tables here is my query:

```
tbl_out AS (
SELECT 
PRG_NAME,
CASEREFERENCE,
STARTDATE,
STATUS,
ENDDATE,
LASTWRITTEN,
CLOSURE_REASON,
--these columns were made to match the tbl_check table--
TO_CHAR(NULL) AS Reviewer,
TO_DATE(NULL) AS Month_Schedule_Date, 
TO_CHAR(NULL) AS Month_REASON, 
TO_DATE(NULL) AS Month_Start_Date, 
TO_DATE(NULL) AS Month_End_Date, 
TO_CHAR(NULL) AS MONTH_Resubmit_MILESTONE, 
TO_CHAR(NULL) AS MONTH_MILESTONE_ACHIEVED, 
TO_DATE(NULL) AS MONTH_APPROVED_DATE, 
--at 1 month--
OUTCOME_DATE, 
Outcome_Reference_ID, 
Outcome_EMP_SITUATION, 
Outcome_Work_Job_Business,  
Outcome_Employment_Type, 
Outcome_NUM_JOBS,  
Outcome_NAICS,
Outcome_NAICS_Desc,
Outcome_NOC,
Outcome_NOC_Desc,
Outcome_JOB_Nature,
TO_NUMBER(Outcome_WORK_HOURS),  
TO_NUMBER(Outcome_WAGE),  
Outcome_Change_Employment,
TO_NUMBER(Outcome_NUM_EMP_Change),
Outcome_LAST_UNEMP_DATE,
Outcome_Attend_School, 
Outcome_STUDENT_STATUS,
Outcome_STUDENT_Type,
Outcome_EMP_CATEGORIES,
Outcome_Got_Service,
Outcome_Right_Service,
Outcome_Seek_Help_Again,
Outcome_Recommend_Program,
Outcome_Didnot_Seek_Employment
FROM outcome 
),
tbl_check AS (
SELECT 
PRG_NAME,
CASEREFERENCE,
STARTDATE,
STATUS,
ENDDATE,
LASTWRITTEN,
CLOSURE_REASON,
--info from tbl_out--
TO_DATE(NULL) AS OUTCOME_DATE,  
--at 6 months--
TO_CHAR(Reviewer), 
TO_DATE(Month_Schedule_Date), 
TO_CHAR(Month_REASON), 
TO_DATE(Month_Start_Date), 
TO_DATE(Month_End_Date), 
month_Review_Reference_ID, 
month_outcome AS MONTH_EMP_SITUATION, 
Month_Work_Job_Business, 
Month_Outcome_Employment_Type, 
month_NUM_JOBS,
month_NAICS, 
Month_NAICS_Desc,
MONTH_NOC,
Month_NOC_Desc,
Month_JOB_Nature,
TO_NUMBER(MONTH_WORK_HOURS),
TO_NUMBER(MONTH_WAGE),
Month_Change_Employment,
TO_NUMBER(Month_NUM_EMP_Change),
MONTH_LAST_UNEMP_DATE,
Month_Attend_School,
Month_STUDENT_STATUS,
Month_STUDENT_Type,
Month_EMP_CATEGORIES,
Month_Got_Service,
Month_Right_Service,
Month_Seek_Help_Again,
Month_Recommend_Program,
Month_Didnot_Seek_Employment,
TO_CHAR(MONTH_Resubmit_MILESTONE), 
TO_CHAR(MONTH_MILESTONE_ACHIEVED), 
TO_DATE(MONTH_APPROVED_DATE) 
FROM checkpoint 
)
SELECT * FROM tbl_out
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tbl_check
```

however, I still get this error:
[image]

I was wondering if anyone could please tell me how I can fix my query so that the query runs properly? Thank you

Comment: The columns in your two CTEs are in different orders. For example, in the first one Reviewer is the 8th column., in the second one it's the 9th column. That's causing different datatypes to be in matching positions, not just what looks like non-matching data. Rearrange the columns in one or both CTEs to they align properly.

Comment: thank you so much! it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns in your two CTEs are in different orders. For example, in the first CTE `Reviewer` is the 8th column, but in the second CTE it's the 9th column. That's causing different datatypes to be in matching positions, not just what looks like non-matching data.

When you do:

```
SELECT * FROM ...
```

the projection has the columns in the order they are defined in the CTE; it doesn't automatically reorder them based on name, say; there's no requirement for the names to be the same (and they aren't the same for a lot of your columns).

Rearrange the columns in one or both CTEs to they align properly. Or list the columns in each select list instead of using `*`, but in this case that's probably not helpful. In general avoid `*`, but it is sometimes a valid and sensible choice.

This is nothing to do with the nulls, other than you've maybe put those in the wrong place.

---

Incidentally really, and somewhat personally, rather than doing things like:

```
TO_CHAR(NULL) AS Reviewer,
TO_DATE(NULL) AS Month_Schedule_Date,
```

I would usually cast to the right data type:

```
CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(30)) AS Reviewer,
CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS Month_Schedule_Date,
```

etc., matching the target data type - including string length and number scale/precision for clarity. It's somewhat a matter of taste; but there are four versions of `to_char()`, which all return `varchar2`, but it still feels a bit ambiguous.

Comment: thanks for the great advice, will change the the columns using CAST!